# Size a background image to fit container

Tags: css, background-image, aspect-ratio

I want to stretch a background image (an SVG that may not be as big as it's container) to stretch or shrink to 100% of its container's width and 100% of its container's height.

If we have a background image that is narrower than its container:

```
background-image: url("../img/sky-gradients-01.svg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I want something that works similar to

```
object-fit: fill
```

a CSS rule which "stretches the image to fit the content box, regardless of its aspect-ratio."

I've tried:

```
/* stretches to fit the width, but maintains the aspect ratio, clipping the bottom */
background-size: 100%;

/* fits the height, but maintains the aspect ratio, leaving space at the both sides */
background-size: 100% 100%;

/* fits the height, but maintains the aspect ratio, leaving space at one sides */
background-size: contain;

/* stretches to fit the width, but maintains the aspect ratio, clipping the bottom */
background-size: cover;

/* original image size, space at sides and possibly bottom */
background-size: auto;
```

In all cases, all the background options maintain the aspect ratio. Are there any options that will fit without honoring the aspect ratio?

Comment: you need to edit the SVG and make sur you set preserve ratio to none

Comment: The SVG didn't have a preserve attribute. Are you suggesting I add it, or disable it if it is set?

Comment: you have to add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` tp the SVG; check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

Answer (score -2):

If nothing else works, try using an image editor  to make the image more rectangular.